# Getting array of object with limit and offset doesn't work using mongodb

Tags: mongodb, limit, slice, offset

First let me say that I am new to `mongodb`. I am trying to get the data from the collection
Here is the document in my collection student:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5979e0473f00003717a9bd62"),
    "id" : "l_7c0e37b9-132e-4054-adbf-649dbc29f43d",
    "name" : "Raj",
    "class" : "10th",
    "assignments" : [ 
        {
            "id" : "v_539f65c2-9f45-4d92-b05e-973cf08cc571",
            "name" : "1"
        }, 
        {
            "id" : "v_539f65c2-9f45-4d92-b05e-973cf08cc572",
            "name" : "2"
        }, 
        {
            "id" : "v_539f65c2-9f45-4d92-b05e-973cf08cc573",
            "name" : "3"
        }, 
        {
            "id" : "v_539f65c2-9f45-4d92-b05e-973cf08cc574",
            "name" : "4"
        }, 
        {
            "id" : "v_539f65c2-9f45-4d92-b05e-973cf08cc575",
            "name" : "5"
        }, 
        {
            "id" : "v_539f65c2-9f45-4d92-b05e-973cf08cc576",
            "name" : "6"
        }
    ]
}
```

the output which i require is

```
{
   "assignments" : [ 
            {
                "id" : "v_539f65c2-9f45-4d92-b05e-973cf08cc571",
                "name" : "1"
            }, 
            {
                "id" : "v_539f65c2-9f45-4d92-b05e-973cf08cc572",
                "name" : "2"
            }, 
            {
                "id" : "v_539f65c2-9f45-4d92-b05e-973cf08cc573",
                "name" : "3"
            }, 
            {
                "id" : "v_539f65c2-9f45-4d92-b05e-973cf08cc574",
                "name" : "4"
            }, 
            {
                "id" : "v_539f65c2-9f45-4d92-b05e-973cf08cc575",
                "name" : "5"
            }, 
            {
                "id" : "v_539f65c2-9f45-4d92-b05e-973cf08cc576",
                "name" : "6"
            }
        ]
}
```

for this response i used the following query

```
db.getCollection('student').find({},{"assignments":1})
```

Now what exactly I am trying is to apply limit and offset for the comments list I tried with `$slice:[0,3]` but it gives me whole document with sliced result
but not assignments alone so how can I combine these two in order to get only assignments with limit and offset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to `aggregate` rather than `find` because `aggregate` allows you to project+slice.

Given the document from your question, the following command ...

```
db.getCollection('student').aggregate([
    // project on assignments and apply a slice to the projection
    {$project: {assignments: {$slice: ['$assignments', 2, 5]}}}
])
```

... returns:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5979e0473f00003717a9bd62"),
    "assignments" : [ 
        {
            "id" : "v_539f65c2-9f45-4d92-b05e-973cf08cc573",
            "name" : "3"
        }, 
        {
            "id" : "v_539f65c2-9f45-4d92-b05e-973cf08cc574",
            "name" : "4"
        }, 
        {
            "id" : "v_539f65c2-9f45-4d92-b05e-973cf08cc575",
            "name" : "5"
        }, 
        {
            "id" : "v_539f65c2-9f45-4d92-b05e-973cf08cc576",
            "name" : "6"
        }
    ]
}
```

This represents the `assignments` array (and **only** the `assignments` array) with a slice from element 2 to 5. You can change the slice arguments (`2, 5` in the above example) to apply your own offset and limit (where the first argument is the offset and the limit is the difference between the first and second arguments).

If you want to add a match condition (to address specific documents) to the above then you'd do something like this:

```
db.getCollection('other').aggregate([
    /// match a specific document
    {$match: {"_id": ObjectId("5979e0473f00003717a9bd62")}},
    // project on assignments and apply a slice to the projection
    {$project: {assignments: {$slice: ['$assignments', 2, 5]}}}
])
```

More details on the match step [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/).

Comment: thanks for your answer this works. But how can use find in the same query means this query gives me all the documents in the collection but if i want that particular document means like by some unique id.

Comment: Are you asking how you can find **and** project? If so then I have updated the answer to show use of the `$match` stage.